# Sliding window reports caching

Tags: python, flask, caching, redis

I have api endpoint that takes as an input some data with "date_from" and "date_to" fields.

When the request is made it initiates the generation of report. These "date_from" and "date_to" fields are used to to generate `(date_to - date_from).days` amount of subrequests. Based on each of these subrequests, hash is generated that is used either to get subresponse from redis database by hash or to make some equations and then save this subresponse to redis. In the end all subresponses are aggregated and returned as actual response.

I had a use case, where all the data is already stored in redis, but on long ranges of date_to and date_from it is still `(date_to - date_from).days` amount of requests to the cache database.
So I decided to also to store the final response of the request in redis in the same fashion by generating hash.

My problem is that these reports are generated regularly with the sliding window of date_from and date_to. For example, yesterday `date_from = "2017-03-08" date_to = "2020-05-07"` but today it would be `date_from = "2017-03-09" date_to = "2020-05-08"`. Which means that

1. Most of report is cached, but the amount of days slows the process incredibly
2. Very similar report was ready yesterday and can be accessed witihin seconds, but it is not full and there is no way to know that they are similar.

Here is my code

```
def generate_report(self, serialized_data):
    result = {
            'deviation' : []
             }
    total_hash = hashlib.sha256(str(serialized_data).encode()).hexdigest()
    total_target = self.redis.get(total_hash)
    if not total_target:
        for date_from, date_to in self.date_range:
            serialized_data['media_company']['date_from'] = \
                                                date_from.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            serialized_data['media_company']['date_to'] = \
                                                date_to.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            hash = hashlib.sha256(str(serialized_data).encode()).hexdigest()
            target = self.redis.get(hash)
            media_company, context, validator = \
                                    self.prepare_for_validation(serialized_data)
            if not target:
                target = validator.check({'media_company': media_company, **context})
                self.redis.setex(hash, timedelta(days=180), json.dumps(target))
            else:
                self.redis.expire(hash, timedelta(days=180))
                target = json.loads(target)

            result['deviation'].append(target['deviation'])
            result['date'] = [str(date_to) for date_from, date_to in self.date_range]
        total_target = result
        self.redis.setex(total_hash, timedelta(days=180), json.dumps(total_target))
    else:
        total_target = json.loads(total_target)
    return total_target
```

**total_hash** represents the hash of initial data,

**self.date_range** represents the array of date ranges for subrequests,

**hash** represents the hash for subqueries

Could you recommend a better way of caching data or may be ways to speed up this algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using redis pipeline rather than individual get commands in the loop, I'm not sure of python code on how to do this but following prototype may help you

```
p1 = self.redis.pipeline()
if not total_target:
  for date_from, date_to in self.date_range:
     #use pipeline here to get target for each day.
     hash = hashlib.sha256(str(serialized_data).encode()).hexdigest()
     p1.get(hash)

#use other pipeline here to set values and expires base on result
#also compute target_toal
p2 = self.redis.pipeline()
for result in p1.execute():
   if not result:
      -- p2 set value with expiry
   else
      -- p2 set expiry
```

Comment: This was a huge speed up! Thanks